# How to submit form on `v-text-field`'s append-inner click?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, vuetifyjs3

How can I submit a form when the append-inner icon is clicked?

```
<v-form @submit.prevent="onSubmitForm">
    <v-text-field label="label"
              @click:append-inner="() => {/* what? */}"
              :rules="myRules.rule"
              :append-inner-icon="'custom:SendIcon'"
              variant="outlined" class="pa-5 pb-0"></v-text-field>
</v-form>
```

Is there a way to do this?
I basically want it to make it so that the `onSubmitForm` callback gets the `SubmitEventPromise` so it can be used for validation. Using form submit, I want to have submit on enter as well as submit on inner icon click.

Comment: Did you try out `@click:append-inner="onSubmitForm"`?

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim tried it. the click event doesn't get the "SubmitEventPromise" event in it's callback.  I need it to have a `SubmitEventPromise` for validation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can trigger [requestSubmit](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/requestSubmit) on a [template ref](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/template-refs.html#accessing-the-refs) on the form:

```html
<v-form ref="formRef" @submit.prevent="onSubmitForm">
  <v-text-field
    @click:append-inner="$refs.formRef.$el.requestSubmit()"
    ...
  />
</v-form>
```

(since the template ref is used to call a method on the HTML element, this is a valid use of template refs)

---

The v-form also provides a `validate()` method in [its default slot props](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-form/#slots-default), so you could also use that to get to the SubmitEventPromise:

```html
<v-form @submit.prevent="onSubmitForm" v-slot="{validate}">
  <v-text-field
    @click:append-inner="() => onSubmitForm(validate())"
    ...
  />
</v-form>
```

but I think in this case, the version with the template ref is cleaner.

---

Btw. I think from the [Material Design guidelines for text field icons](https://m3.material.io/components/text-fields/guidelines#5c8a5f07-b1a5-455f-bf76-7ff0d724f6b0), the appended icons should be used for actions that affect the input, not the form. So a submit button could go in the [`#append`](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-text-field/#slots-append) slot, but not in the `#inner-append` slot. Make of that what you will.